# Reusing multiple variables within a WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, code-reuse

I have a single `map` field that holds both latitude and longitude separated by a semicolon. What I need to do is separate the two and then do calculations from another given latitude and longitude to calculate the difference.

Note, please ignore... how I split the map string field, the b.id = a.id, and the calculations I'm doing on lat and long. They're not important here.

```
WHERE 

/* Here's where I get the values for lat and long from the map field */
(
    SELECT 
    /* lat from map field */ as lat, 
    /* long from map field */ as long
FROM some_table AS b 
    WHERE b.id = a.id AND b.key = 'map'
)

/* Here's where I use them to do some calculations... */
lat <= (" . ($lat + $radius / 40075) . ")
AND lat >= (" . ($lat - $radius / 40075) . ")
AND long <= (" . ($long + $radius / 40075) . ")
AND long >= (" . ($long - $radius / 40075) . ")
```

I know this won't work, but I'd like to know how to do it so I'm not re-selecting the map value every time I use `lat` and `long`.

Comment: on a second look. i think i misunderstood your question. Have you had a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is `lat` in the SQL a different variable than your PHP variable `$lat`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a position to test this so hopefully someone will resolve any syntax errors should they arise.

```
SELECT SUBST(map, 1, STRPOS(map, ",") - 1) AS lat, SUBSTR(map, STRPOS(map, ",")) AS long
FROM some_table
WHERE
    lat BETWEEN ($lat - $radius / 40075) AND ($lat + $radius / 40075)
AND 
    long BETWEEN ($long - $radius / 40075) AND ($long + $radius / 40075)
```